# How to convert an object into an array in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have this object in Flask and I want to convert it into an array. Please help.

Object:

```
{"Mortality Rate": [{"mortalitycount": 700}, {"mortalitycount": 650}, {"mortalitycount": 700}]}
```

Expected output:

```
[700, 650, 700]
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Just traverse the dictionary with the key and concatenate the dictionary values to a final list.

```
obj = {"Mortality Rate": [{"mortalitycount": 700}, {"mortalitycount": 650}, {"mortalitycount": 700}]}

key = "Mortality Rate"
a = [list(d.values()) for d in obj[key]]
print(a)
# [[700], [650], [700]]
b = []
for ls in a:
    b.extend(ls)
print(b)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I am getting this error sir: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str